# Java-netbeans: Cannot run program "${platforms.default_platform.home}\bin\java

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, cvs

I'm working from CVS via netbeans on windows 7, a week ago, I was able to compile and run my Java web application. however, after updating from cvs this error pops up.

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "${platforms.default_platform.home}\bin\java" (in directory "E:\ws2\project"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I'm sure I pointed java/bin in the system environment variable.

Am I missing a setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem after updating Netbeans recently.

I was able to get it working by re-adding Java 1.7 in the platforms configuration of NetBeans.

I'm using NetBeans 7.4.

(Right click on project) > Properties > Libraries Category > Manage Platforms Button
Add Platform pointing to Java 1.7 or 1.6 JDK as desired. 
Select new Platform in Properties window and select "ok".

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm getting this error and all my projects refuse to run...I did nothing but close the app and then opened it again and everything was borked. I can't even run a one line hello world.

When I try to re add the jdk it twilight zones me by stating that the JDK I select (the same old one) is unselectable for some unstated reason. I'm guessing it's corrupted.

Comment: @DavidSaintloth You can test your theory by reinstalling the JDK. Hopefully you've found a fix.

Comment: I had just done a checkout. Resolving by changing JDK didn't help, but going into manage platforms and re-selecting the (only) JDK, Close, OK and it started building again. Thank you!